# ¿Cómo puedo cambiar el color de los botones de una cuadricula al hacer click en ellos?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, botón

Aquí está el código, pero al ejecutarlo solamente cambia el color del último botón sin importar cual presione cuando llamo a la funcion `press` con `command`:

```
from tkinter import *
from create_cells import *

class Board():
    def __init__(self):
        self.Br = Tk()
        self.Br.title("Board")
        self.boardFrame = Frame(self.Br).grid(column=0,row=0)
# The next instructions create a new board with buttons to chose a cell 
        for self.r in range(0,20):
            for self.c in range(0, 40):
                self.newButton = Button(self.Br,text="",command=self.press)
                self.newButton.grid(row = self.r, column = self.c)
        self.startButton = Button(self.Br,text="Start",bg ="indian red").grid(row=40, column=0,columnspan=10, sticky= W+E)
        self.restartButton = Button(self.Br,text="Restart",bg ="indian red").grid(row=40, column=20, columnspan=10, sticky= W+E)
        self.pauseButton = Button(self.Br,text="Pause",bg ="indian red").grid(row=40, column=10, columnspan=10, sticky= W+E)
        self.exitButton = Button(self.Br, text="Exit", bg ="indian red", command=self.Br.destroy).grid(row=40, column=30, columnspan=10, sticky= W+E)


        self.Br.mainloop()

    def press (self, *args):
        self.newButton.configure(bg = "gold")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Al crear los botones en un ciclo `for`, en cada iteración reasignas al atributo de instancia `newButton` la referencia al nuevo botón creado en esa iteración. Por lo tanto, `newButton` al terminar tu ciclo, hace referencia al último botón instanciado. Esto hace de hecho inútil el atributo, dado que sin importar que botón se pulse `self.newButton`  en `press` siempre hace referencia  último y es a éste al que se le cambia el fondo.

La solución es pasar a la callback la instancia del botón que ocasiona su llamada, lo cual puedes hacer posponiendo a después de la instanciación del botón la asignación de la callback a `command` y usar `functools.partial` para pasarle la referencia al botón.

Un ejemplo reproducible:

```
from functools import partial
import tkinter as tk



class MainFrame(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent, *args, **kwargs)

        for row in range(0, 20):
            for column in range(0, 40):
                new_button = tk.Button(self, text="")
                new_button.grid(row=row, column=column)
                new_button["command"] = partial(self.press, new_button)

    def press(self, btn):
        btn.configure(bg="gold")
        btn.configure(activebackground="gold")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    MainFrame(root).pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

### Edición

Puedes pasar los argumento que quieras a la función usando [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functools.html#functools.partial),tanto posicionales como de tipo keyworld, su firma es:

```
functools.partial(func, *args, **keywords)
```

Si quieres pasar también las coordenadas en la matriz del botón simplemente debes hacer algo como:

```
new_button["command"] = partial(self.press, new_button, row, column)


def press(self, btn, row, col):
    print(row, col)
    btn.configure(bg="gold")
    btn.configure(activebackground="gold")
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, es posible que a la funcion press se le pueda pasar también
la posicion del boton como argumento:
                new_button["command"] = partial(self.press(row,column), new_button)

Comment: Por supuesto, puedes pasarle lo que quieres, pero no como muestras. El primer argumento siempre es una referencia ala función, tal como lo haces la ejecutas y pasas su salida (None). He editado la respuestas,mira al final de ella.

Comment: @FJSevilla Hi In this same example, if what I want is that I change the color of the button that I clicked on and keep the rest as it is, and likewise I go to another button and click on it and the one that had changed its color before comes back to stay like the other buttons, it is possible I tried it like this example and I couldn't... help me please

it's the same thing except that if it's already yellow, I click on a button and I want it to be red, I click on another and the one that was in red turns yellow and the one I clicked on turns red and so on